# Is it possible to call two bower.commands functions in one grunt task?

Tags: gruntjs, bower

I recently began learning how to use GruntJS and Bower. My mission is to use bower's programmatic api with a grunt task. What I am trying to accomplish is calling bower.commands.info to compare a filepath in the bower.json of the desired project with an local filepath in which I want it to go. It should then install said project into the local path. So far it only calls bower.commands.info, but forgets about bower.commands.install.  I have even swapped the order in which they are called to see if it would affect anything. It only displayed info, but did not install. Hopefully my code will explain more:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    grunt.initConfig({
        //this is where the grunt tasks go

        //this is where the package info is read in
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'), //use comma if adding npm tasks

        'bower-install': {
            target: {
                //point to the html file that is to be updated
                html: 'index.html',

                //Optional:
                //ignorePath: 'wxProj/',

                //customize how stylesheets are included
                cssPattern: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{filePath}}"/>',

                //customize how scripts are included
                jsPattern: '<script type="text/javascript" src="{{filePath}}"> </script>'
            }
        }
    });

    //feel free to load any npm tasks here
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-install');

    //this function uses bower to pull some files from my github
    grunt.registerTask('extract', function(name){
        var bower = require('bower'),
            bower_done = this.async(),
            wxdesk_contents = '{\n' +
                '"directory" : "wxdesk/bower_components"\n' +
            '}',
            vendor_contents = '{\n' +
            '"directory" : "vendor/bower_components"\n'+
            '}';

        bower.commands.info(name, 'dest')
        .on('error', function(){
            bower_done(false);
        })
        .on('end', function(dest){
            bower_done();
            grunt.log.writeln(dest);
            if(dest == 'wxdesk'){
                grunt.log.writeln('written to wxdesk!');
                //change .bowerrc's "directory" property
                grunt.file.write('.bowerrc', wxdesk_contents);
            }
            else
            {
                grunt.log.writeln('written to vendor!');
                grunt.file.write('.bowerrc', vendor_contents);
            }
        });

        bower.commands.install([name], {save: true})
        .on('log', function(result){
            grunt.log.writeln(['bower', result.id.cyan, result.message].join(' '));
        })
        .on('error', function(){
            bower_done(false);
        })
        .on('end', function(results){
            bower_done();
            //run grunt bower-install
            grunt.task.run('bower-install');
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the issue to my problem, besides lack of sleep. I called bower_done(); in bower.commands.info, when it should only be in the install to finish the task thread. 
In other words:

```
bower.commands.info(name, 'dest')
        .on('error', function(){
            bower_done(false);
        })
        .on('end', function(dest){
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //bower_done(); <= This guy should not be here!
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            grunt.log.writeln(dest);
            if(dest == 'wxdesk'){
                grunt.log.writeln('written to wxdesk!');
                //change .bowerrc's "directory" property
                grunt.file.write('.bowerrc', wxdesk_contents);
            }
            else
            {
                grunt.log.writeln('written to vendor!');
                grunt.file.write('.bowerrc', vendor_contents);
            }
        });

        bower.commands.install([name], {save: true})
        .on('log', function(result){
            grunt.log.writeln(['bower', result.id.cyan, result.message].join(' '));
        })
        .on('error', function(){
            bower_done(false);
        })
        .on('end', function(results){
            ///////////////////////////////
            bower_done(); //<= should be here on the final task to end the async
            ///////////////////////////////
            //run grunt bower-install
            grunt.task.run('bower-install');
        });
```